# Trouble with a proof in Dummit and Foote

Tags: galois-theory

Let $K/F$ be a Galois field extension and let $\alpha \in K$.  We would like to show that the roots of the minimal polynomial $m_\alpha(x)$ for $\alpha$ are the distinct Galois conjugates of $\alpha$ all of which have multiplicity 1.

Ok, now for the proof.  Let $G = Gal(K/F) = \{1,\sigma_1, ... , \sigma_n \}$.  Consider the elements 
$$
\alpha, \sigma_1(\alpha), ... \sigma_n(\alpha).
$$
Let 
$$
\alpha, \alpha_1, ... , \alpha_r
$$
denote the distinct elements above and let 
$$
f(x) = (x-\alpha)(x-\alpha_1)\cdots(x-\alpha_r).
$$
We want to show that $m_\alpha(x) = f(x)$.  The first step is to show that $f(x) \in F[x]$.  Let $\tau \in G$.  Then $\{\tau, \tau \sigma_1, ... , \tau \sigma_n \} = G$.  Therefore $\tau$ permutes the elements $\alpha, \sigma_1(\alpha), ... \sigma_n(\alpha)$.  Why does it follow that $\tau$ permutes the elements $\alpha, \alpha_1, ... , \alpha_r$??

Answer (score 2):

The argument is that if you multiply all the elements of the group by one element of the group, you will get all the elements of the group. There will be no missing elements or duplicates. This basically follows from the fact that each element of the group has an inverse.

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that $\tau\alpha\in\{\alpha,\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_r\}$. So $\tau$ defines a map $\{\alpha,\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_r\}\to \{\alpha,\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_r\}$.

Now, $\tau$ is an automorphism and in particular it is injective. So its restriction to $\{\alpha,\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_r\}$ is also injective, and thus also surjective and hence it is a permutation.